# Jackson: Serializing object fields to array

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm pretty new to `Jackson`, but I stumbled upon the following problem:

I'd like to serialize a simple object to an array of its fields.
So considering the following class:

```
public class UserModel {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String company;
}
```

I get the following json:

```
{
   "id":"cec34b58",
   "firstName":"foo",
   "lastName":"bar",
   "email":"foo@bar.com",
   "company":"FooBar"
}
```

But what I'd like is the following:

```
[
   "cec34b58",
   "foo",
   "bar",
   "foo@bar.com",
   "FooBar"
]
```

I'd like to avoid using a [custom serializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) if there's an easier way. Reading the [Jackson Annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations), I don't immediately see something that allows immediate conversion of the model. Google only advises serialization of Java's `Collections` to json but nothing to go from a Java `Object` to a json array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This does NOT require custom serializers but simple annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public class UserModel {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help! I do wish it came better known, it is indeed neat for some use cases; can compress message sizes for closely-coupled systems.

Comment: See also the [JsonPropertyOrder](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html) annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Your scheme is fairly custom, so you'll have to do via custom serializer thing.

Please also note that I would suggest you to revise it as adding / removing new field / changing order would be much trickier in this case especially if you can't release both client and server simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method *toList()* and *fromList()* on your class UserModel that converts your class to/from a List.  Instead of serializing your UserModel object with Jackson, you serialize the list.